# How to merge the header cells of the .csv file when exported on the button clicked by using lightning web component and apex code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, button, excel, merge

I need to downlaod the data to .csv file by clicking on the button. I'm using lightning web component and apex class for doing this. But now I want to merge few of the header cells of the .csv file using lightning web component and apex code and also want two lines as header lines. Can anyone help me on this on how to arrange the headers of the .csv file. I'm attaching the screenshot for the reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CSV files do not support merged cells, or indeed any style or formatting.

If you need to control the output format, consider using a document generation product from the AppExchange to generate a native spreadsheet file.

Comment: No need to get the AppExchange involved, just need to use a format that supports formatting. Microsoft's Open Office format is at least feasible without too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into LWC and Apex for your question, you might have misunderstood an important point about CSV files i.e., they do not retain styling or formatting. So, in a CSV file, you cannot merge cells. You might temporarily see the merged cells in CSV file when you are formatting it (*or merging cells*) because MS Excel facilitates this so users can save the file as different formats (*such as .xlsx or .xls*). However, if you save/close the file and reopen it, you will observe that the formatting is lost.

If you save the file shown in the question as CSV, close it and open it again, the merging will be lost. if you open the same file in an editor like notepad or notepad++, you will see the data as follows:

```
Departments,,,,,,,TotalMarks,,,,,Average,,
Name,Age,Gender,Class,Section
```

So, unless you move away from CSV to another format, I would say you are working on an impossible task.